# Fixed field of the $n$-th powers of the non-zero elements of a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $E/F$ be a finite Galois extension with Galois group $G$. Also, let $n$ be a natural number.

> **Question**: Why is $(E^{\times n})^G = F^\times \cap E^{\times n}$?

It is not so hard to show "$\supseteq$", i.e. that every element $z \in F^\times \cap E^{\times n}$ satisfies $\sigma(z) = z$ for all $\sigma \in G$.

But why is "$\subseteq$" true? <strike>More precisely, if $x \in F^\times \setminus E^{\times n}$, then why is there a $\psi \in G$ such that $\psi(x) \neq x$?</strike> (I realized that this does not make sense indeed...)

Could you please help me with solving this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure why the statement after "More precisely" is what you want. Don't you just want to know, if there's an $n$-th power in $E$ that is fixed by all elements of $G$, then it's in $F^\times$? And doesn't that just follow from the definition of a fixed field?

Comment: I don't understand your sentence starting with "More precisely". The implication in that sentence is certainly not true: every element of $F$ is fixed by $G$ by the definition of the Galois group. To show the inclusion, do you know that $E^G = F$?

Comment: I think in your now stricken sentence you just switched the order, in that you meant to ask about $x \in E^{\times n} \setminus F^{\times}$. The existence of such a $\psi$ in that case is guaranteed by the fundamental theorem of Galois theory, namely that $E^G = F$.